# How to override position of primefaces OneMenu?

Tags: css, primefaces

[image]

How to override primefaces OneMenu in order to see it over captcha, ie below? My selectOneMenu have no any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the menu panel doesn't have enough space to fit in the lower part, instead it's positioned above, as the aligning of the panel is being set by javascript ([PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.alignPanel](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#1022)), using the jQuery UI [.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) method which allows you to position an element relative to the window, document, another element, or the cursor/mouse, without worrying about offset parents, and the default value for `collision` attribute is flip ([In PrimeFaces 5 it's flipfit](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/5_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#990)) resulting the positioned element overflows the window in some direction, or to move it to an alternative position.

In this case you could implement one of these three solutions:

- extend the space on the lower part, maybe adding margin to the
  captcha, in this way the panel would fit in bottom.
- *OR* change the hight of the panel

  ```
  <p:selectOneMenu height="100" >
  ```

  Making it a bit shorter so it can fit.
- *OR* you can override the `PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.alignPanel` function
  to set the `collision` attribute to `none`, in the position function:

  **PrimeFaces 5**

  ```
  PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.alignPanel = function() {
     if(this.panel.parent().is(this.jq)) {
         this.panel.css({
             left: 0,
             top: this.jq.innerHeight()
         });
     }
     else {
         this.panel.css({left:'', top:''}).position({
             my: 'left top'
             ,at: 'left bottom'
             ,of: this.jq
             ,collision: 'none' // changing from flipfit to none
         });
     }
  }
  ```

  **PrimeFaces 4**

  ```
  PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.alignPanel = function() {        
     var fixedPosition = this.panel.css('position') == 'fixed',
     win = $(window),
     positionOffset = fixedPosition ? '-' + win.scrollLeft() + ' -' + win.scrollTop() : null;

      this.panel.css({left:'', top:''}).position({
         my: 'left top'
        ,at: 'left bottom'
        ,of: this.jq
        ,offset : positionOffset
        ,collision: 'none' // changing from default flip to none
     });
  }
  ```

  Of course you should call it in the *document.ready*, and when you update the component.
   I don't recommend this approach too much, but sometimes it's the only solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For necessary SelectOneMenu add style `top` find an optimal value and apply it. For me it is:

```
#registrationForm\:facultyList_panel {
    top: 413px !important;
}
```

**UPDATE 09.07:** It does not helps for another screen resolution. The question is still relevant.

Comment: If you're being that explicit in your css is it really necessary to use important?

Comment: @VeenarM yea, because we provide overriding the default primefaces value. But it does not helps for all cases: for another screen resolutions it looks not good. The question is still relevant